# SQL Exception Column not valid

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to capture a UUID that will be used to redirect the URL in my selenium script however its returning a column not found. What am I overlooking here?

MySQL:
[image]

Script:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Post your code as text. Also, the line that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try the query

```
SELECT ui.uuid
FROM connect_staging.user_invitations ui
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```